# Can not synchronize WSO2 node services

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have 2 nodes of WSO2 in cluster. Log says that both nodes connected to cluster. But each node has its own service list. The thing I want is when i configure service in one node, it must be synchonized to another one.

All things configured as in this tutorial 
 https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+a+Cluster#SettingupaCluster-Configuringtheloadbalancer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have used SVN based deployment synchronization. Could please try rsync as mentioned in [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+rsync+for+Deployment+Synchronization). This is the more recommended synchronization mechanism.

Comment: i'll try, but now there is no svn config in my carnon.xml

Comment: Then that should be the reason. There is no way to synchronize artifacts among ESB nodes. But anyways, please use rsync. It's more convenient.

Comment: @AzatNugusbayev svn is considered obsolete with the current product versions. I'd recommend to use shared filesystem (NFS, GusterFS) to share the "synapse" folder which can give you fill active-active configuration. Using rsync the services are synchronized, but you need to consider the synchronization direction (ilke master-slave setup)